# How to update mannual entries in grub.cfg?

Tags: fedora, grub2, dual-boot, manjaro

I have a fedora + manjaro installation.
Although **grub2** shows all the boot options, but when manjaro is selected it gives the infamous kernel panic:

```
kernel panic-not syncing: VFS:unable to mount root fs on unknown block(0,0)
```

After going though several arch forums I found that if I press **e** at the grub2 and edit the last line of manjaro boot sequence from

```
initrdefi /boot/intel-ucode.img
```

to

```
initrdefi /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-4.9-x86_64.img
```

It boots into manjaro.

Naturally, I opened fedora, did a `grub2-update` to get the **grub.cfg** file and made the required changes in it, but those changes are not getting reflected into the grub2 boot screen (i.e I have to *manually* add `/boot/initramfs-4.9-x86_64.img`  to boot into manjaro, otherwise it gives a kernal panic)

How would I make the changes in the *grub.cfg* permanent? 
 Additionally, I read somewhere that we should not make changes to grub.cfg as it'll change if the kernal is upgraded. What's the best course of action here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have the same issue using the fedora 25 grub2 to boot both: fedora and Manjaro.

what i did:

## WARNING, YOU CAN RREALLY SRCREW THE CONFIG, SO BE CAREFUL!

As root:

```
vi /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

it opens the text editor so you can add the line you need, wich can be found in the /boot from the other distros. you will need the initramfs info. use taht and add it as you did in de grub

initrdefi /boot/intel-ucode.img

/boot/initramfs-4.9-x86_64.img <--- this is the line you must add.

it worked for me until the Majaro with kernel 4.11 and  fedora 26 aside. im struggling a little now

Note: you must repeat the drill only if the manjaro kernel changes (if you want to boot into the version with the new kernel.)